# Java alternative of product function of python form itertools

Tags: java, python, python-itertools

In one of my java program, I need to use exactly what product function from itertools offers, permuting an array reapeating k times.( `perm=itertools.product(arr,repeat=k)`).

for ex. for arr=[4,5] and k=3, the output should be:

```
(4, 4, 4)
(4, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 4)
(4, 5, 5)
(5, 4, 4)
(5, 4, 5)
(5, 5, 4)
(5, 5, 5)
```

I want to ask if there is any utility or something in java which can facilitate this in java? I have been looking for it over the internet, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Please share something if you know what could be done in this case.

Comment: this will help https://github.com/samagra14/itertools_java

Comment: Thanks for providing the resource. I guess the function I have been looking for is not there

Comment: which function?

Comment: The Product function, it is not there.

Comment: @VipulTyagi it is here: https://github.com/samagra14/itertools_java/blob/master/src/Itertools.java#L359

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

I have used python [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) code as reference.

```
public class Util {

    public static <T> List<Collection<T>> product(Collection<T> a, int r) {
        List<Collection<T>> result = Collections.nCopies(1, Collections.emptyList());
        for (Collection<T> pool : Collections.nCopies(r, new LinkedHashSet<>(a))) {
            List<Collection<T>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Collection<T> x : result) {
                for (T y : pool) {
                    Collection<T> z = new ArrayList<>(x);
                    z.add(y);
                    temp.add(z);
                }
            }
            result = temp;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        product(List.of(4, 5), 3).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 4, 4]
[4, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 4]
[4, 5, 5]
[5, 4, 4]
[5, 4, 5]
[5, 5, 4]
[5, 5, 5]
```